# Issues installing Ruby 1.9.3-p392

Tags: installation, rvm, ruby-1.9.3

I'm trying to setup Ruby 1.9.3-p392 using RVM. I'm getting the below error:-

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #configure
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #download
There is no checksum for 'https://rvm.io/binaries/ubuntu/12.04/i386/ruby-1.9.3-p392.tar.bz2?rvm=1.18.3' or 'bin-ruby-1.9.3-p392.tar.bz2', it's not possible to validate it.
If you wish to continue with unverified download add '--verify-downloads 1' after the command.

Downloading https://rvm.io/binaries/ubuntu/12.04/i386/ruby-1.9.3-p392.tar.bz2 failed.
Mounting remote ruby failed, trying to compile.
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/krishna/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p392, this may take a while depending on your connection...
There is no checksum for 'http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p392.tar.bz2' or 'ruby-1.9.3-p392.tar.bz2', it's not possible to validate it.
If you wish to continue with unverified download add '--verify-downloads 1' after the command.

There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

Looking at the above error messages, I don't consider it safe to do an unverified download. Can anyone please tell me how to get this installed the right way using RVM ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using older version of RVM `1.18.3`, the current version is `1.21.2`, just update RVM to get the updated checksums for all new rubies and binaries:

```
rvm get stable
```

OR:

```
rvm get head
```